# If $f(x, y)$ is harmonic, show that $f(x^2 - y^2, 2xy)$ is also harmonic

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

This is a solved example from **Calculus A Complete Course by Robert Adams** , section 12.5 .
I think this example has been solved incorrectly :

**Example 9:** If  $f(x, y)$ is harmonic, show that $f(x^2 - y^2, 2xy)$ is also harmonic.

**Solution:** Let $ u = x^2 - y^2 $ and $ v = 2xy $. If $ z = f(u, v) $, then

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= 2x f_1(u, v) + 2y f_2(u, v) \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} &= -2y f_1(u, v) + 2x f_2(u, v)
\end{align*}

Differentiating again,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} &= 2f_1(u, v) + 2x(2x f_{11}(u, v) + 2y f_{12}(u, v)) \\
&\phantom{=} + 2y(2x f_{21}(u, v) + 2y f_{22}(u, v)) \\
&= 2f_1(u, v) + 4x^2 f_{11}(u, v) + 8xy f_{12}(u, v) + 4y^2 f_{22}(u, v)
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} &= -2f_1(u, v) - 2y(-2y f_{11}(u, v) + 2x f_{12}(u, v)) \\
&\phantom{=} + 2x(-2y f_{21}(u, v) + 2x f_{22}(u, v)) \\
&= -2f_1(u, v) + 4y^2 f_{11}(u, v) - 8xy f_{12}(u, v) + 4x^2 f_{22}(u, v)
\end{align*}

Therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} = 4(x^2 + y^2) (f_{11}(u, v) + f_{22}(u, v)) = 0
$$
because f  is harmonic. Thus, z = f(x^2 - y^2, 2xy) is a harmonic function of x  and y .

**My First Question:**
I wonder why he is sure that $f_{12} =f_{21}$ at the end , because we know that the condition for $f_{12} =f_{21}$ is f and $f_1$ and $f_2$ and $f_{11}$ and $f_{12}$ and $f_{22}$should all be continuous. How does he conclude that $f(x^2−y^2,2xy)$ is continuous just based on f(x,y)? Because we don't have the modified function expression.

**My Second Question:**
Suppose $f(x^2−y^2,2xy)$ works in Laplace, but how we are sure that it is harmonic?

Comment: If $f$ is analytic so is $f(z^{2})$.

Comment: @geetha290krm would you please explain more

Comment: Or: holomorphic (or antiholomorphic) maps $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}\to V\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ are harmonic morphisms, meaning they pull back harmonic functions to harmonic functions.

Comment: This result is almost obvious if you are allowed to use Complex Analysis. Harmonic functions are (locally) real parts of analytic functions and $f(z^{2})$ is analytic if $f$ is. Note that $x^{2}-y^{2}$ and $2xy$ are just real and imaginary parts of $(x+iy)^{2}$.

Comment: Also note, $(u_xv_x+u_yv_y)~(f_{12}(u,v)+f_{21}(u,v)) = (4xy-4xy)~(f_{12}(u,v)+f_{21}(u,v))$ so whether or not the double cross derivatives are equal, they will vanish from the expression.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yeah I did that myself and it worked but the thing was Adams summed up before joining expressions and that made me curious. Thank you!

Comment: @geetha290krm Nice explanation. Thanks!